# Prevent mate display settings override nvidia-settings

Tags: nvidia, mate-desktop, display-settings

I had Mate to configure my dual screen setup with `mate-display-properties`, but now I'm using `nvidia-settings` for configuring it.

The new configuration seems to work, on login (lightdm) and on [Awesome](https://awesome.naquadah.org/) the configuration made with `nvidia-settings` loads fine.

On Mate instead the `mate-display-properties` application is overriding `nvidia-settings`, I verified this by deactivating the **Mate Settings Daemon** and the Mate display configuration wasn't loaded but also the rest of the settings that I need.

How to reset or remove the old settings made with `mate-display-properties` to prevent Mate to override `nvidia-settings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While posting and testing I found a workaround but still, if someone knows how to remove `mate-display-properties` configuration would be better.

Anyway for sharing:

1. Login into Mate
2. Once logged launch `nvidia-settings`
3. Configure the displays and `Apply`
4. Now launch `mate-display-properties` and you'll see that now is set to the same configuration of `nvidia-settings`.
5. Don't touch anything and click `Apply`.
6. Now the override made by `mate-display-properties` takes still place but with the same configuration of `nvidia-settings` so is invisible to the user.

Comment: I think I'm a bit late but I also recently had this issue.  I removed `~/.config/monitors.xml` and that appears to have disabled the overriding config